# Override jest-junit default output location?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, xunit, jest-junit

How can I override the default output directory and file name [jest-junit](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit#readme)?

I would like to customise the output configuration of  output when using Jest, but it still ends up in the default location, i.e. `./junit.xml` in the project root folder.

---

#### My configuration

In *package.json*:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-junit": "^10.0.0",
  }
```

In *jest.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  testMatch: [
    '**/*.spec.js',
  ],
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [ 'jest-junit', {
      outputDirectory: 'test_reports',
      outputName: 'jest-junit.xml',
    } ]
  ]
};
```

#### Expected result:

- A file with the test result at `./test_reports/jest-junit.xml`

#### Actual result:

- A file with the test result at the default `./junit.xml`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution

change `package.json` script from

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit"
},
```

to just

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --ci"
},
```

---

### Explanation

The problem is that reporters configuration have been provided to both the `jest.config.js` file as well as cli arguments to the `test` script in package.json. The CLI options has higher precedence and does not provide the `outputDirectory` and `outputName`, the test result will revert to the default `junit.xml`.